# What is the difference between passing .png and image/png in the accept attribute of a file type input?

Tags: html, file, input

I'm making a component where it will have a parameter for the `accept` in an `input` where `type="file"` and I realized that you have two ways of allowing to accept an image of a certain file (e.g. .png file).

You can pass `accept=".png"` or `accept="image/png"` and it looks like the same... but is it the same?

Is there any difference between using `.png` and `image/png` ?

What is the difference between this two options:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".png" />
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/png" />
```

I'm concerned about this because if there is any difference from one to the other, I want to make it optional to choose between both, if not, I will just use only one option.

Answer (score 0):

First one allows you to upload mp3, mp4 files in android/chrome as the latter doesn't